# JavaFX use Nearest Texture Sampling on Material

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, sampling, javafx-3d

As a small easter-egg in a school project I'm trying to add a simple Minecraft-Clone into a JavaFX-UI programme.
While the rendering and technology is working absolutely fine, troubles are appearing due to the texture sampling.

Because everything is in 3D and thus rendered as a TriangleMesh, the texturing is done using a PhongMaterial. However, the texture is obviously sampled in LINEAR-Mode. For the pixel-art graphics ob Minecraft this is obviously detremental.

Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out, how this might be overcome - if it is even possible. Hopefully the Stackoverflow-Intelligence can work its wonders here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to make a scaled JavaFX 3D texture Pixel-Perfect at different distances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723429/how-to-make-a-scaled-javafx-3d-texture-pixel-perfect-at-different-distances).